# Embedded Linux: Hardware access

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi, to access the GPIO pins or hardware peripherals (eg. I2C, SPI), you need to be running the program that accesses these as root. Or you can add the user running that program to the group for that peripheral (eg. the group i2c for I2C).

My question: In the real world (eg, some piece of machinery running embedded linux) is it standard practice to simply add a user to every user group for each peripheral that the program needs? Is there a better way of doing this?

My second question: How does this work when, for example, your using C to directly access hardware registers rather than via /sys. The only ways I can think of doing this is to run as root all the time which is not a good idea at all OR write a kernel module that deals with accessing the registers, while the user space program communicates with that module (which all seems like a lot of work if there are more "recommended" ways). How do programs normally access hardware registers on an embedded Linux setup?

Comment: when you want to print something on the screen you call printf() from a function right you dont need any special privileges to do stuff on the hard drive, fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), fclose, and so on.  There are times for special cases, but it is definitely possible to design a driver and application interface that doesnt require special permission.  They may not have done it that way but doesnt mean it needs to be that way.

Comment: I'd love to see the actual reason for this being specified as "not a real question".

Comment: I dont know why those folks down voted, but you have not asked a question with an answer, instead a question looking for opinions.  flame war, etc.  As written it might be a better at programmers stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

1. Adding all users to all the required groups would be painful. You have a couple of options. You can make use of the [setuid and setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) mechanism. With this mechanism, the process takes on the uid gid of the executable, and can then access the devices with the right access level. Or, you can leverage the [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) mechanism, where you can allow users to execute programs as root with some fine grained control.
2. The general model in modern OSes is to delegate the hardware access to a kernel resident device driver. In *nix OSes, the device driver then offers an API to the programs in the user space via the standard filesystem calls (open, close, read, write, ioctl). For most drivers, the ioctl call is effectively the kitchen sink for the entire API offered to the user space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, it's been a great help. So in reference to the bit about hardware register access, a device driver could be written that delegates access to the register?

Comment: That's the idea. The driver is kernel resident, and can access physical addresses. You can also write users space drivers too. Even in that case you would still write a minimal driver for the device that will use mmap mechanism to map the device physical addresses to virtual addresses in the userspace. Then you can write a program that encodes the bulk of the logic to manipulate the device. But the regular device driver approach offers other advantages.

Comment: Oh, and you should check. Your kernel may already have the drivers that you need, that will allow you to access the necessary peripherals. Don't conclude that you have to write these drivers yourself.

Comment: Using a kernel driver (#2) is probably the most portable and modular method, for both the device driver and application perspectives.

Comment: This starts from a mistaken premise - adding 'users' to groups is not in the least bit painful, because there are typically fairly few distinct specialized user id's on such a system.  And whatever ID's there are have to be created somehow, which is the time to put them in appropriate groups.  In the few cases where there are a lot (consider an Android phone), creation of users and adding them to groups is a fully automated process driven by application metadata parsed at install.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are provided with Raspberry Pi's Raspbian/Debian release for access to GPIO.  Check out the back issues of [The MagPi](http://www.themagpi.com/) for numerous examples in Python and other languages.  And also [the example projects here](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/).

Comment: This does not seem to be very relevant to the main subjects of the question.

Comment: He seems to believe that using GPIO requires root access, but I do not believe that to be the case since it it explicitly supported on RPi through libraries provided for the purpose.  The RaspberryPi Foundation actively encourage use of the board's GPIO features - they really don't make it that hard!  The question is not tagged with any language, and most examples for RPi happen to be in Python, but that is not universal.  The links provide a net rather than a fish, which is ultimately more useful perhaps.

Comment: General suggestions for direction to look typically belong in comment, not an answer.  As for the permission issue, it would depend entirely on the permission bits of the mode bits on the GPIO device nodes - something that may vary from distribution to distribution - and precisely the kind of design tradeoff that the question is asking about.

Comment: Accepted - the first sentence is my answer in that context. Raspbian is the recommended and defacto-standard distribution for Raspberry Pi, and the best supported.